# Creating new column with information from rows from other column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I've prepared a large number of data frames with information from PDF files.
Please find an exemplary PDF here: https://www.estv.admin.ch/dam/estv/de/dokumente/allgemein/Dokumentation/Zahlen_fakten/Steuerstatistiken/steuerbelastung_gemeinden/2010/Steuerbelastung%20in%20den%20Gemeinden%202010.pdf.download.pdf/2010_steuerbelastung_gemeinden_d.pdf

My Pandas data frame will contain tax rates for municipalities in Switzerland from pp. 6 - 63 (leaving out pages with only text).

Each of the municipalities belong to a "Canton". For example, on p. 6 all municipalities belong to the "Kanton Zürich" as indicated in the first row. On p. 7, most of the municipalities belong to the "Kanton Bern".

I want to create an additional column with the Canton information (and drop the Canton rows).

Unfortunately, I don't know how to assign the Canton information to the respective municipalities.

Comment: I'm not sure the PDF link is relevant, it would be more helpful to see an example of the dataframe and a reproducible example of what you are aiming to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I've found an easy solution. See below if you have a similar problem.

```
df['Kanton'] = df['Gemeinde'].str.contains('^Kanton|^Canton')
df.loc[df['Kanton'] == True, 'Kanton'] = df['Gemeinde']
df.loc[df['Kanton'] == False, 'Kanton'] = np.nan
df['Kanton'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace = True)
df = df[~df['Gemeinde'].str.contains('^Kanton|^Canton')]
```